# IE issue (function not being called document.ready)

Tags: jquery

I've been wading through all of the other questions regarding IE challenges, but I'm no closer to understanding why my Ajax function is called in Chrome and Firefox but not IE8.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title></title>
<script src="/jQuery/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="messageList"> </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadMessages();

}); 
function loadMessages() {
      var myInbox = "https://x/SecComm/ajax_inboxResults.cfm?folderID=0";
      $.get(myInbox,function(data){
          $("#messageList").html(data);
      });

  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm sure I'm doing something really stupid, but since I've only been at this a week or so, I'm a bit stumped!

Awaiting the arrival of "Irene", thx for your time, KW

Comment: should be called in IE8 - are you sure its not just a javascript error due to the first line in `loadMessages()` ?

Comment: Are the `<cfoutput>` tags intentional? Also, you can use [IE developer tools (F12)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx) to debug and actually see if it isn't being called or if `loadMessages` is causing an error - have you done this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with what `<cfoutput>` does, but that seems to be the only non-standard thing in your code, so perhaps that is causing the problem.

Can you do a test without that piece in there to see if it works?

In general, the way to debug in IE is simply by commenting out pieces of the code to see if it eliminates the error. Once you've found the piece that is causing the error, you can finally start to fix it.

Comment: That last paragraph is wrong, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I second that: you've left a piece of ColdFusion code in there. Just look in your Developer's Tools (F12 for IE8 and higher) and you should see a syntax error on the first line of the loadMessages function.

Comment: Thx for taking a look. The <cfoutput> is just a coldfusion tag inserting a dynamic to the ajax call. I've pulled it out and replaced it: Still no luck, i'll try the IE dev tools and see if i can find any more useful info. thx again

Comment: Folks, I'm an idiot.  I'm testing on my home laptop.  It's ie7 i'm having problems with.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: My chosen method of debugging in IE may not be the same as yours, but it's not "wrong." The IE developer tools are far from great, and I generally find it easier & much faster to debug JS errors using the method I described.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I had a problem with IE not firing the document ready event, it was because there was inline javascript on the page which added a flash swf to the DOM (this makes IE cry). If you are loading any swfs to your page, I'd use a library such as swfobject.

Comment: Hi folks, thanks again for your time.  I've stripped it down to the bare bones (see updated code).  I get no javascript errors in IE, just don't get anything back from the ajax call (I do in chrome/firefox).  Anything else anyone can think of?

Comment: The scripts are working.  i just modified the ajax call to a template including the word "hello" and it was returned successfully by ie7.  must be formatting of returned data.  thx to you all.  (and if any of you are on the east coast, stay safe!)